# How to deal with mismatch of timesteps in target variable and features in forecasting problem?

Tags: machine-learning, data, forecasting

### Background Info:

I am working with some climate data where I want to predict crop yields with my dataset containing climate- and satellite-derived features.

This is a time series regression forecasting problem and I want to put it through XGBoost and Lasso to generate my predictions. However, there is a mismatch in the sample frequency between my features and target variable; the features are recorded weekly, and the target variable is recorded yearly.

At the moment, I am using a wide-format table as my input dataset to the ML models, but I feel like my models are not generating accurate predictions when the input table is formatted with the wide-format, since there are less samples compared to if I used a long-format table.

### Data Table Reference:

For reference, the wide format table looks something like this, where the suffix represents a week number on a feature:

| ID | Year | crop_yield | precip1 | precip2 | precip3 | max_temp1 | max_temp2 | max_temp3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1100 | 2000 | 32.1 | 5.3 | 3.0 | 3.1 | 13.3 | 15.3 | 3.1 |
| 1100 | 2001 | 31.6 | 6.6 | 3.2 | 1.1 | 11.3 | 12.3 | 6.1 |
| 5903 | 2000 | 41.2 | 3.4 | 0.5 | 2.1 | 10.3 | 18.3 | 8.1 |
| 5903 | 2001 | 27.7 | 1.7 | 3.8 | 8.1 | 12.3 | 16.3 | 5.1 |

And the long format table would look something like this:

| ID | Year | crop_yield | Week | precip | max_temp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1100 | 2000 | 32.1 | 1 | 5.3 | 13.3 |
| 1100 | 2000 | 32.1 | 2 | 3.0 | 15.3 |
| 1100 | 2000 | 32.1 | 3 | 3.1 | 3.1 |
| 1100 | 2001 | 31.6 | 1 | 6.6 | 11.3 |
| 1100 | 2001 | 31.6 | 2 | 3.2 | 12.3 |
| 1100 | 2001 | 31.6 | 3 | 1.1 | 6.1 |
| 5903 | 2000 | 41.2 | 1 | 3.4 | 10.3 |
| 5903 | 2000 | 41.2 | 2 | 0.5 | 18.3 |
| 5903 | 2000 | 41.2 | 3 | 2.1 | 8.1 |
| 5903 | 2001 | 27.7 | 1 | 1.7 | 12.3 |
| 5903 | 2001 | 27.7 | 2 | 3.8 | 16.3 |
| 5903 | 2001 | 27.7 | 3 | 8.1 | 5.1 |

### Question:

Would it be advisable to use the long format table as the input to my ML models? I feel like the identical crop yields for each associated ID and year would throw my models off.

In addition, is there a better way to frame my data that I haven't explored yet?

Answer (score 0):

To deal with mismatch of timesteps, you have to find a balance between all those mismatched timesteps according to your objective.
For example, if your objective is to have a prediction for the next quarter, your learning data should be adapted to quarters.

learning data < 1 quarter: get the mean values of all weeks that last quarters.

learning data > 1 quarter: repeat the yearly value to every corresponding quarter, or make a (logistic?) regression to simulate the quarterly evolution over years.

This is a simple example to explain the idea, but real cases might require further investigation to define the right timestep according to objectives.